# 'unexpected operator' en bash

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo este codigo:

```
#!/bin/bash
    regex_suspenso='^[0-9]';
    
        while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 col16 col17 col18 col19 col20 col21 col22 col23 col24 col25 col26 col27 col28 col29 col30 col31 col32 col33
        do
            if [ ! "$col31" =~ "$regex_suspenso" ]; then
            
            echo "Suspenso";
            
            fi
                      
        done < $INPUT
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
c_bash.sh: 17: [: G1: unexpected operator
c_bash.sh: 17: [: 5: unexpected operator
c_bash.sh: 17: [: 5: unexpected operator
c_bash.sh: 17: [: 7: unexpected operator
c_bash.sh: 17: [: 15: unexpected operator
c_bash.sh: 17: [: 6: unexpected operator
```

La columna `$col31` es 'G1'. Por ello en el error devuelve 'G1' y todos los valores que encuentra en el bucle. **¿Qué esta mal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes poner el condicional con doble corchete:

```
if [[ ! "$col31" =~ "$regex_suspenso" ]]; then
```

Con eso debería de funcionar

Comment: Ahora me aparece este error "[[: not found"

Comment: ¿Puede que estés ejcutando el script con `sh <nombre_script>`? Si en la cabecera del script está `#!/bin/bash`y lo ejecutas con  `bash <nombre_script>` o  `./<nombre_script>` debería entender el doble corchete

Comment: Correcto ha sido eso. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegro, de nada!